# ASP.net : Why page displayed as text?

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am using the below function

> [ Server.Transfer(url) ]

In my code for redirect to **html** page ,

But why the **html** page is display as text in browser?

Code In **Global.asax** file :

```
Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   '' Accpeted Firefox browser only :
   If Not GlobelApp.ValidBrowser(Request.Browser) Then
       Server.Transfer("browser.html")
       Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Html page code **browser.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Update Browser</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
              font-family: 'Droid Sans Arabic';
              src: url('fonts/droid-sans-arabic.ttf') format('truetype');
            }
            * { font-family:'Droid Sans Arabic', 'Segoe UI'; font-weight:lighter; color:#444; direction:rtl; }
            h1 {  font-weight:lighter; text-align:center; }
            a { color:#3276B1; text-align:center; }
            p { line-height: 33px; text-align:center; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:550px; margin:120px auto 10px;">
            <img src="img/firefox.png" style="width:180px;margin:0px auto; display:block;" />
            <h1 style="padding-top:15px;">تحديث المتصفح</h1>
            <p>
                لكي يعمل النظام لديك عليك تحميل متصفح الفايرفوكس Firefox بأحدث إصدار <br />
                <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/">تحميل المتصفح الفايرفوكس Firefox</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please guide me

Comment: share your code what you have done so far.

Comment: Think it would be easier if you bought a few books and started from scratch.

Comment: @Phill  check the code

Comment: @Almelyan - code seems correct, it should work, try to put one button on page and on click event use the same code line to transfer.

Comment: Is there something like that Content-Type? Can you specify that redirection content is an HTML? I mean at the server side code, not in html meta tag.

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal I tried it and it worked by button `Click` event, but I want to use it in the `Application_BeginRequest` event for check the **browser**

Comment: @UğurAldanmaz I don't understand your questions at all, if you mean where I used it , that is in file **Global.asax** file in event `Application_BeginRequest`, the function worked normal in pages.
just when begin `http request` doesn't work

Comment: @UğurAldanmaz thanks a lot now I know why it doesn't work ^_^

Comment: Pick up a book. And read.

Comment: I KNEW THAT WHY @Phill -_- I am always reading since 5 years

Comment: Show the answer of question @Phill

Answer (score 1):

When response from the server we must specify that the content of response is **HTML** by put the header **Content-Type** in response headers

in normal ASP Pages is default but when redirect from **Global.asax** I think is no headers in the response

so instead of `Server.Transfer` function use `Server.TransferRequest(path, preserveForm, method,headers)`, so we can put the **Content-Type** header

here the code is worked OK

```
Dim headers As New NameValueCollection
headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html")
Server.TransferRequest("browser.html", False, "GET", headers)
```

and thanks to **@rajeshmpanchal** and **@Uğur Aldanmaz** for help ^_^